# Count IDs only if matches with date from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the C_Status table that looks like this:

```
ID(pk)  Time_Period Statuses
1   2020-10-01  Silver
2   2021-01-01  Gold
3   2020-11-01  Bronze
1   2020-12-01  Bronze
1   2021-03-01  Platinum
2   2020-10-01  Bronze
3   2021-04-01  Diamond
2   2021-04-01  Bronze
1   2020-04-01  Gold
```

And the table Registrations that looks like this:

```
C_ID(pk) Reg_Date  
1       2020-12-06
2       2021-04-22
3       2020-11-14
```

I need to count the number of customers per status per month, only when a customer registered in that particular month and year. I need to match only the year and month of registration.

The following query shows only an exact match accounting for the day as well, and I want only by Month and Year.

```
SELECT FORMAT(Time_Period , 'yyyy-MM') AS Year_Month, Statuses,
COUNT(ID) AS Count_Status
FROM C_Status c
JOIN Registrations r ON r.C_ID = c.ID
WHERE r.Reg_Date = c.Time_period
GROUP BY FORMAT(Time_Period , 'yyyy-MM'), Statuses
ORDER BY 1
```

How can I compare the two tables only by month and year, and not by dd\mm\yyy? No need to account for months with no registrations.

The output should be:

```
Year_month Statuses Count_Status
2020-11     Bronze  1
2020-12     Bronze  1
2021-04     Bronze  1
2021-04     Diamond 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a condition based on month and year when joining tables :

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATETRUNC(month, Time_Period) , 'yyyy-MM') AS Year_Month, Statuses,
       COUNT(ID) AS Count_Status
FROM C_Status c
JOIN Registrations r ON r.C_ID = c.ID 
     AND DATETRUNC(month, Time_Period) = DATETRUNC(month, Reg_Date)
GROUP BY DATETRUNC(month, Time_Period), Statuses
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: `GROUP BY EOMONTH(Time_Period)` or `GROUP BY DATETRUNC(month, Time_Period)` and selecting the same is probably more efficient. Also joining on date intervals rather than functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(Time_Period , 'yyyy-MM') AS Year_Month, Statuses,
       COUNT(c.ID) AS Count_Status
FROM C_Status c
JOIN C_Registrations r ON 
      YEAR(Time_Period) = YEAR(Reg_Date) 
     AND MONTH(Time_Period) = MONTH(Reg_Date)
GROUP BY FORMAT(Time_Period , 'yyyy-MM'), Statuses
```